# Hip hop lyrics - "You’re just a little guy"

Tags: identify-this-song, rap, hip-hop

“You’re just a little guy—something on the fly—you are my baby doll you not my baby..” or something like that.  I’ve tried listening to the clip but people are talking over it.

Comment: [2pac's I Get Around](https://genius.com/2pac-i-get-around-lyrics)?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me it is...

## 2pac - I Get Around

From a [lyrics page](https://genius.com/2pac-i-get-around-lyrics) we can see something related to what you mention in the question:

> You picked the wrong guy, baby, if you're too fly
>   You need to hit the door, search for a new guy

Full video in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqJAnQTwmJs.